# modprobe ath9k at startup?

Tags: 10.10, wireless, startup, modules

I have finally managed to find a solution to make my wifi stable in ubuntu 10.10. I have had problems with my ASUS ul30vt and the Atheros AR9285 but by installing the latest compat-wireless from yesterday my internet is finally stable.

I seriously thought of installing win7 again. But one minor problem i have is that the wifi is not turned on automatically from startup so everytime i startup i have to go to terminal and `sudo modprobe ath9k` and then the wireless turns on. I have tried to make that command in startup applications but that does not work. Can i make a script or something that will turn it on from startup, or is there an other simple solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/etc/rc.local` is a silly place to put it IMO.

Whack `ath9k` on the end of `/etc/modules` (the file that's supposed to handle which modules are also added by default)

Comment: There we had the problem. Some other module (ath9k_htc) was set to start...

Answer (score 3):

You commented `ath9k_htc` was being loaded instead of `ath9k`. Maybe you should blacklist `ath9k_htc` in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf. `ath9k` will probably be loaded instead.

Answer (score 0):

just add your commands to `/etc/rc.local` file. 
 This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
 value on error.

In your case you could do it like this:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
modprobe ath9k
if [ $? == 0 ]
then
exit 0
else
exit 1
fi
```